# Plot on ggmap by using city and state

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, ggmap

I have a map of the USA, ready to go:

`mygggmap <- get_map(location = "United States", zoom = 4)
g <- ggmap(myggmap)`

The next step is to plot some major cities.

I understand I can create a layer to plot my major cities by their longitude and latitude, something like:
`g <- g + geom_density2d(data = citydata, aes(x = lon, y = lat))`

but I am wondering if there is a way to plot by the actual name, city and state?  Since ggmap is layered over the Google Map API, this should be possible, correct?

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer.  It is simple.  Use the geocode function:

`geocode("SEATTLE")`

returns

```
        lon        lat
     -122.3321   47.60621
```

Thanks for the support everyone.  Even though I just got a 'tumbleweed' badge.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explore further, you could also supplement your original data with data from the `zipcode` package. It has zip codes for about 43K US cities. For more information, you can check out the link http://www.r-bloggers.com/my-first-r-package-zipcode