# R - Simple City State Plot on a Map for large numbers of records currently without geoencoding every record individually?

Tags: r, google-maps, geocode

I am fairly new to R and the multiple R mapping packages I haven't completely flushed out their capabilities yet nor necessarily discovered all of the efficient ways to do things; so I apologize if there is an obvious answer but any help is appreciated.

The problem I am trying to solve has the following components.

1. I want to create a heat map over a map of the United States based
   only on city and state data. I do not have zip code or geoencoding
   data.
2. Each day I generate data of a about half a million records that usually have some
   form of City and State contained in a single field in them. The data
   is inconsistent as far as formatting and frequently has errors or
   non-usable data. This I am generally OK with, but it plays into
   possibly affecting other functions.
3. The heat map (sum or count) is desired to be looked at on daily, weekly,
   and monthly or ad-hoc intervals. So manually doing data preparation each
   interval would likely be inefficient and also limit or not be
   efficient enough to use public APIs.
4. A very large majority of the data will have the same values. A quick
   check of the values showed that one value makes up over 10% of the
   data consistently over time and the top 100 values (when formatted
   correctly) make up easily 25% or more.
5. The program generating the data is vendor supplied and cannot be programmed to go and
   retrieve the geocode data itself and I am basically left to do it in
   R.
6. I only have read only access to the data so cannot create additional
   fields to store information like geo-encoding information in the
   transaction records and at this time I cannot create another table in the same database
   to store the information.

I am aware of the geocode function and this similar post:
[question] [Plot on ggmap by using city and state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752009/plot-on-ggmap-by-using-city-and-state)
as well as the getGeoCode built into RgoogleMaps that handles the various spacing of the city state well.

> getGeoCode("Anchorage AK")
>          lat        lon 
>     61.21806 -149.90028

#### What I am looking for guidance or help with is the following:

A) Is there a City library that contains the generic map plot information or is there a basic map package that has this built in that does not need to go out to the net for each record?

B) Is there a simple plot heat map that is something similar straight forward as the following as most examples of map plots I have seen to date are quite larger pieces of code just to call the map function.

```
plot(DataSource, CityCol, ValueCol)
```

C) **And really the primary question**, how (or is there a way) to build a common library or array of already identified locations in R that I could load each time on run-time and if it is not contained in that library only then go out and geocode it using a web resource. Almost a lookup table or library that is really just a custom data array?

Comment: I've used this data set from Sujee Maniyam's blog for geo code information: http://sujee.net/tech/articles/geocoded/

Comment: MaxMind http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ & these folks http://sujee.net/tech/articles/geocoded/ have a fairly extensive city/state -> lat/lon database. Be wary of using the google R code since you may be violating the terms of service. Even if you geocode them, what type of heatmap do you expect to generate given that you only have lat/lon for each city?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I think that goes to question A, if I get them all geocoded which over the last few hours I've made some data clean-up coding to group results so it is not such a large data set (under 300k records for several months combined vs. 10s of millions per month). On the **B)** question the RgoogleMaps 'getGeoCode' I have found pretty efficent and flexible basically ignoring spaces. Taking it back to take into account spaces might also be something I need to do when using a third party data file.